How many years do namekians live?
In Dragon Ball Daima, a namekian was introduced who lived thousands of years. Is it ever mentioned in any official Dragon Ball Source how many years do namekians live?

It's worth noting that the namekian resident in the Demon realm was stated to have his lifetime extended multiple times (likely begining from the time the rest of the namekians fled the demon realm, but that is speculation). We do know that when at least some namekians left the demon realm, piccolo had come to earth, which was a time period long to enough to create to legend of the dragon balls on earth, for kami to split, and for kami and piccolo to become old (hence piccolo wishing for eternal youth). We can judge from piccolo's wish that they do not live forever, like the Kai's appear to.
